# Word Automation: Write RTF text without going through clipboard

Tags: vba, automation, ms-word

I am trying to **replace the current selection in Word (2003/2007)** by some **RTF string** stored in a variable.

Here is the current code:

```
Clipboard.SetText(strRTFString, TextDataFormat.Rtf)
oWord.ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.Selection.PasteAndFormat(0)
```

Is there any way to do the same thing without going through the clipboard. Or is there any way to push the clipboard data to a safe place and restore it after?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Put the RTF in a file instead of the clipboard, then insert from the file, e.g.

> `Selection.InsertFile FileName:="myfile.rtf", Range :="", _
>   ConfirmConversions:=False, Link:=False, Attachment:=False`

Comment: Thanks Joel. To make this answer more broadly useful than the context of the original question, let me add that the `InsertFile` method is also on the `Range` property (which is accessible, for example, on  `Word.Document`, `Word.Document.Sections` elements, etc.)

Answer (score -3):

You can use a RichTextbox to convert RTF to text or vice versa.

```
RichTextBox r = new RichTextBox();
r.Rtf = strRTFString;
Console.WriteLine(r.Text);
```

Comment: Wouldn't this convert the RTF string to plain text?

Comment: Mmmn, my answer doesn't seem to bear any resemblance to the question. Wonder why I even wrote that?