# Exporting MS Access 365 report with Rich text to Word strips formatting as well as all boxes etc. -

Tags: ms-access, report, rtf, richtext

How can I get around this? By now there must be some way?

`DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, Me.letter_sent, acFormatRTF, dir & d & "-" & c & "-" & n & ".rtf", False, , , acExportQualityPrint`

Comment: Could export to PDF instead.

Comment: Review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22326/word-automation-write-rtf-text-without-going-through-clipboard/22335 and https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_access-msoffice_custom-mso_2010/insert-access-2010-rich-text-from-memo-field-to/69ef074b-856e-43a6-a639-f5475302c20b